# How to do prefetch in React Native and persist data to local storage without blocking the UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multithreading, react-native

Let me share the problem with my app:

When user initiates the app, it will directly navigate to Home Screen. While user is in home screen I would like to make bunch of api requests to fill the local db with the data for the "possible" screens that user can go.

In native applications I know that this case can be handled by a different task (parallel programming) however, react native is built in with Js and doesn't support multi threading.

I know there are some libraries that implements WEB WORKER's in react native, however what is the best practice to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I use redux to overcome this. I will call the api and it will map the data to the redux store. All the screens are connected to the store. Since, the data is already loaded in the store I will just display it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need a write operation to local db, not in memory redux store. In addition, the question states that I don't want to loose main thread to stuck with getting data, parsing and writing to db.